# Pandas read_csv produces unexpected behavior, why?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I've got a large tab-separated file and am trying to load it using

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(..., sep="\t")
```

however, the process crashes with the error being

```
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 8 fields in line 1743925, saw 12
```

Nothing apparent wrong with that particular line when I printed it out manually. Feeling confident that there is nothing wrong with my file, I went and tried to calculate the field counts myself...

```
from collections import Counter 

lengths = []
with open(...) as f:
    for line in f:
        lengths.append(len(line.split('\t')))

c = Counter(lengths)
print(c)
```

...and got the result `Counter({8: 2385674})`. So I was wondering what does `pandas` do differently, but the error is raised inside a `.pyx` file and hence I cannot plant a breakpoint there. What could be the cause of this? Where is my expectation flawed?

Comment: What's the content of lines 1743923 thru 1743928?

Comment: @ThomasKimber Nothing peculiar. If I gather all those lines into a separate `.tsv` and include the original header, the code runs without any issue.

Comment: I just wonder how does `pandas` arrive at the number `12`, which, to the best of my knowledge, comes out of nowhere. How can I find out?

Comment: It applies the separator to the current line, splitting the current row into fields which are then mapped onto the (assumed to be) static number of fields present in the file. If it sees 11 instances of a tab, then it's liable to imagine there are 12 fields, where up to that line, each row might only have 7 separators each (for 8 fields). If you're using quote-shielding of text, or escape characters this can cause this type of error - but your field counter code would have likely identified this. It's a mystery, but it does appear to happen on row 1743925 (possibly a short-row on 1743924?)

Comment: And printing that row out might not help, since tabs can be treated specially/differently depending on the process doing the printing - ideally, you'd want to see the raw content of those rows (even at byte level) and scanning for more than 7 \t values (utf-code 0x09) mixed in there somewhere.

Comment: @ThomasKimber I checked those rows character by character, printing whitespace characters visually. Nothing. Perfectly fine row as far as I am concerned :( As I've said, rows ..23 to ..28, alone, in a different `.tsv`, run without any issue. I'm baffled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue. Turns out the problem was a different `quoting` on csv export and read. The issue was solved by matching `quoting` on `read_csv` with `quoting` on the `to_csv` which created the loaded file. I assume some tabs and newlines were thought to be parts of string literals because of this, hence the assumption of 11 tab characters on one row (they were actually 2+ rows).